# UserDetails and hibernate exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am trying to start my web application, but I get exception:

```
java.util.Collection, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(authorities)]
```

I am sorry for agglutinate code, but SO requires less code and more details.

It is my User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Set<Role> roles;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {return email;}
    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {return password;}
    public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    public Set<Role> getRoles() { return roles; }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> role) {this.roles = role;}
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {return roles;}
    @Override
    public String getUsername() { return email; }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {return true; }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() { return true; }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {  return true; }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {  return true; }
}
```

And it is the Role entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority, Serializable {
    private String name;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {return name;}
}
```

Comment: In your `User` class you have two methods `getAuthorities(..)` and `getRoles(..)` both returns `roles`. Do you need `getAutrhorities(..)` method and also it doesn't have any hibernate `OneToMany` mapping. You may want to remove that and try?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu well, I can't delete method `getAuthorities()`, but I try return `null` in it and I get the same exception

Comment: It is not about what it is returning. Can you add `Transient` annotation on that method and try.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu yes, it helps, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause for this problem. If we put annotation above getters then Hibernate automatically trying create column for other getters which are not annotated. There are two variants:

1) Move all annotations above fields.

2) Add `@Transient` to all getters which are not a columns.